# Confusion re: Lagrange's method

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I'm looking at Stewart's "Calculus" (8th ed). See here:

[image]

What confuses me is that the constraint $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a cylinder, not a 2-d circle. **Figure 2** above seems to be combining the graph of $z=f(x,y)$ with the graph of the level curve of $g(x,y)=1$.

Is Stewart just saving space here or am I missing something?

Comment: The domain is $\mathrm{R}^2$, and that's where the constraint operates, so what Stewart says is correct.

Comment: I think a more clear approach would be to show that the graph of g(x,y) is a cylinder. The graph of the cylinder intersects the graph of f(x,y). We're interested in maximizing f(x,y) along the intersection of these two graphs. From there, he could show the level curves of both f(x,y) and g(x,y). In that view, g(x,y) =1 would be a circle.

Comment: ^^ this strikes me as a more general approach that would work in cases where g(x,y) is a more "flamboyant" function than a simple cylinder. For example, see here: https://sites.lafayette.edu/thompsmc/files/2014/01/Section_14_8.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Stewart wants you to evaluate the function on the circle itself, i.e. in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The picture is in 3D to give you intuition, I guess, even though formally you would only need the values of $f$ on that circle, not anywhere inside...

---

Incidentally, that gives you a way to compute the extrema using 1D calculus. Parameterize the circle as $(x,y) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ for $0 \le t < 2\pi$, and now you seek the extrema of 
$$
f(x(t), y(t)) = x(t)^2 + 2y(t)^2 = \cos^2t + 2\sin^2t = 1 + \sin^2t
$$
over $t \in [0,2\pi)$...